# Watch changes in ionic 3

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I have the following code, I have not managed to get the way to update the changes of stepsCount, I need that every time startPedometerUpdates (), send changes to be able to show them instantaneously. in the variable stepsCount.

what I am looking for is basically to be able to create a watch to detect the changes of `this.stepsCount` or `this.pedometer.startPedometerUpdates().`

Any idea how to do it?
Thank you very much

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform, NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

//Pedometer
import { Pedometer, IPedometerData } from '@ionic-native/pedometer';


@Component({
  selector: 'page-actv-home',
  templateUrl: 'actv-home.html',
})
export class ActvHomePage {

  stepsCount: any = 0;

  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public pedometer: Pedometer,
    public plt: Platform
  ) {
    this.pedometer.startPedometerUpdates()
      .subscribe((data: IPedometerData) => {
        this.stepsCount = data.numberOfSteps;
      });
  }

}
```

**HTML**

```
<ion-content>
    <p>{{ stepsCount }}</p>
</ion-content>
```

**Console log for** `data`

[image]

Comment: Can you add the template(html) code as well.

Comment: @AnuradhaGunasekara ready.

Comment: what is the output ? Can you add a `console.log(data)` inside the `subscribe` method and add the output to the question?

Comment: @AnuradhaGunasekara ready

Comment: output is `numberOfSteps`

Comment: So everytime a new value comes the html and the console is getting updated right?

Comment: No, only the update is shown in the console, but the html is not updated, I want that, the html is updated as well.

Comment: Could you reproduce this in a stackblitz?

Comment: sorry, this only work with cordova. what I am looking for is basically to be able to create a watch to detect the changes of stepsCount or this.pedometer.startPedometerUpdates ().

Comment: Oh right, I didn't notice :) Have you tried `NgZone` or `ChangeDetectorRef`?

Answer (score 0):

I have solution. with `ChangeDetectorRef`, thank you. @AJT_82

```
import { Component , ChangeDetectorRef} from '@angular/core';
import { Platform, NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

//Pedometer
import { Pedometer, IPedometerData } from '@ionic-native/pedometer';


@Component({
  selector: 'page-actv-home',
  templateUrl: 'actv-home.html',
})
export class ActvHomePage {

  stepsCount: any = 0;

  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public pedometer: Pedometer,
    public refdect:ChangeDetectorRef,
    public plt: Platform
  ) {

    // STEPS COUNT DEMO
    if (this.plt.is('cordova')) {
        this.watchSteps();
    }
  }


  watchSteps(){
    this.pedometer.startPedometerUpdates()
        .subscribe((data: IPedometerData) => {
          this.stepsCount = data.numberOfSteps;
          if(this.stepsCount == 10){
            alert('Yes! Your have completed 100 steps');
          }
          this.refdect.detectChanges();
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: Still not working for you?
I'm triying with your solution, but i'm getting not response from the pedometer when i testing with android.